# How to return words which did NOT match?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm passing in 500k words via the `frequentWords` and I'm passing the body of text from the post via `word` which is roughly 500 words to 10k max.
Currently, It checks if any of the words match then puts it into an array and returns it.

But I have changed the system and now instead I want to forget the words which match but instead I want to populate `hardWords` with the ones which did **not match** any of the `frequetWords`.

```
function checkIfWordsMatch(body, callback) {
  const hardWords = [];
  const words = body.split(' ');

  words.map((word) => {
    if (frequentWords.includes(word)) {
      let = hardWords.push(word);
    }
  });
  return callback(hardWords);
}
```

Any advice on how I could do this, I would highly appreciate it as I am not too skilled with this, many thanks!

Comment: Try `if (!frequentWords.includes(word)) {`

Comment: I can't believe I asked such a question, my brain is fried from all the work all day. Thank you so much so simple and yet I couldn't figure it out. If you post it as an answer I can give you credit for it, many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To perform a negative boolean check you can simply add `!` in front of your test, in this case you should change `if (frequentWords.includes(word)) {...` to `if (!frequentWords.includes(word)) {...`.

So, instead of "if frequentWords includes word", your test becomes "if **not** frequentWords includes word".

Answer (score 2):

The answer was a simple `!` at the front of `frequentWords`.

```
function checkIfWordsMatch(body, callback) {
  const hardWords = [];
  const words = body.split(' ');

  words.map((word) => {
    if (frequentWords.includes(word)) {
      let = hardWords.push(word);
    }
  });
  return callback(hardWords);
}
```

Credit to: @FranCarstens

Answer (score 1):

I guess

```
function checkIfWordsMatch(body, callback) {
  const hardWords = [];
  const words = body.split(' ');

  words.map((word) => {
    if (!frequentWords.includes(word)) {
      hardWords.push(word)
  });
  return callback(hardWords);
}
```

Comment: better now missed a thing